# How to make a dynamic path on a package.json script

Tags: testing, automated-tests, yarnpkg, package.json, hardhat

On my `package.json` I have this script
`"test": "hardhat test"`.

I would like to make another one to only run tests from a subfolder, and not the entire test suite.
Something like `"test:single": "hardhat test ./tests/subfolder/${runThisOne}"` and call it like `yarn test:single coolTest` which would result in `yarn test:single ./tests/subfolder/coolTest`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you may be looking for is something like this, at least for npm:

`"test:single": "hardhat test ./tests/subfolder/\"$npm_config_myFolder\"/"`

which could then be used as such:

`npm run test:single --myFolder=coolTest`

Answer (score -1):

For Npm use this,

```
"scripts":{
   "test": "hardhat test",
   "sale": "hardhat test test/Sale.js" // here test will run sale.js 
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer is just the way of a static path.